# Postgresql: Copy different databases into one database with different schema

Tags: database, postgresql

I have three `postgresql` databases in a server: `db1`,`db2`,`db3`. Now I want to save the tables in each db to a new db `dbnew` and distinguish it with `schemas`. Which means that there are three schemas in this database `dbnew.db1`,`dbnew.db2`,`dbnew.db3`. What is the easiest method to realize it?

(p.s.: I have dumped the database to local files.)

I test the answer from @a_horse_with_no_name, it seems to work but there is a new problem as follows:

If in `db1` there is an extension like `postgis`, then I load `db1` with `psql` and rename `public` to `db1` and create a new schema named `public`. I could not create the extension `postgis` for `public` schema as it shows that `extension postgis already exists`. However if I use the command `\dx`, it shows that the extension is in schema `db1` not in `dbnew`. Even if I use `create EXTENSION postgis with schema public` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on backup/plain and restore using psql

I assume, that the schemas in dbnew are created and the rights to schema are set to the user doing all restoring using psql.

Somehow create sql files (backup plain in pgadmin3), the resulting files can be loaded into the dbnew database using psql, but they should piped through sed or grep, so that all tablenames get the schema prefix.

With somehow I meant, backup from original or first restore your backups into a temporary db, if they are no sql yet, and backup them as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all tables are stored in the `public` schema in the source databases

Import the first dump (by running `psql ... -f dumpfile.sql`), then rename the public schema to the new name:

```
alter schema schema public rename to db1;
```

Then re-create the public schema:

```
create schema public;
```

Now do the same thing for the other two database scripts.

Comment: The solution is great, to get the binary backups into the new database, that is very fast. But the second rename will fail, because the schema already exists. What will work is to use "alter table public.<tablename> set schema dbnew;" for each table in the public schema.

Comment: I found if I rename schema with extension, and if I want to create extension in `public` schema, it fails.